# Sort DOM elements based on the sorting of the array elements

Tags: javascript

I have 3 HTML elements and an array with 3 elements.

```js
const args = ['Red', 'Purple', 'Green'];
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;  
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.purple {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="box green">1</div>
<div class="box red">2</div>
<div class="box purple">3</div>
```

I would like to sort the HTML elements in DOM, based on the index of the elements in the array. So for instance, if the array is `['Red', 'Purple', 'Green']`, the red box should be on top, purple in the middle and the green box in the bottom. How can I do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
['Red', 'Purple', 'Green']
.forEach(col => 
  container.appendChild(container.querySelector("." + col.toLowerCase())))
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.purple {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box green">1</div>
  <div class="box red">2</div>
  <div class="box purple">3</div>
</div>
```

If more than one div with the same class

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
['Red', 'Purple', 'Green']
.forEach(col =>
  container.querySelectorAll("." + col.toLowerCase())
  .forEach(div => container.appendChild(div)))
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.purple {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box green">1</div>
  <div class="box red">2</div>
  <div class="box purple">3</div>
  <div class="box red">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.forEach(col => container.querySelectorAll("."+col.toLowerCase()).forEach(n => container.appendChild(n)))` to handle multiple divs with same color

Answer (score 0):

```js
const args = ['Red', 'Purple', 'Green'].map(arg => arg.toLowerCase());

let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.box');

let sortedDivs = Array.from(divs).sort((a, b) => {
  aClass = Array.from(a.classList).filter(clas => args.indexOf(clas) > -1)[0];
  bClass = Array.from(b.classList).filter(clas => args.indexOf(clas) > -1)[0];
  return args.indexOf(aClass) - args.indexOf(bClass);
});

sortedDivs.forEach(div => {
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.purple {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box green">1</div>
  <div class="box red">2</div>
  <div class="box purple">3</div>
  <div class="box red">4</div>
</div>
```